# Sublime Text 2 Can't Type Arrow Keys or Copy Paste Only Letters Work

Tags: sublimetext2

I was using Sublime yesterday and all was fine until suddenly I can not use any special non-alphanumeric characters (for example, CTRL-C or CTRL-V or arrow keys) and it also will not allow the mouse to select anything including the tabs.  I can select an execute menu items but nothing in the file section.  I have tried deleting the settings file and reloading and the problem still exists.

Comment: This is a question for [su].

Comment: Without me doing anything it is working today.  Not sure what changed to cause the issue nor fix it.